# Android doesn't localize strings properly unless they are 'preferred' on the device. Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, android, localization

In my Android app I want to give users the ability to change app language regardless of system settings. I've read multiple tutorials on the subject and arrived at solution that works... but only if all in-app languages are already on system's preferred languages list. This is the settings screen I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/coOSf.jpg

If any of my in-app language is not there then default string resources are used by Android. Has anyone had the same problem? Are there any workarounds?

This is my setup:

1) I have three strings.xml files in three separate folders (values, values-en and values-ru)

2) My in-app language helper method looks like this:

```java
    @Nullable
    public static Context getContextLocalized(@Nullable Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
            configuration.setLocale(getLocale());
            return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It basically takes the locale selected by the user (the `getLocale()` method) and creates a new context with that locale.

3) I have three predefined locales:

```java
new Locale("pl", "PL")
new Locale("en", "GB")
new Locale("ru", "RU")
```

that user can choose from.

4) The way I use `getContextLocalized()` looks like this:

```java
    @NonNull
    public static String getStringLocalized(@Nullable Context context, @StringRes int stringId, Object... args) {
        Context contextLocalized = getContextLocalized(context);
        if (contextLocalized != null) {
            try {
                return contextLocalized.getString(stringId, args);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getStringLocalized: ERROR " +
                        contextLocalized.getResources().getResourceName(stringId) +
                        "! " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR";
            }
        }
        return "NULL";
    }
```

This method is what I use in my Fragments and Activities to extract the desired string.

This solution works great if my system language list contains all my in-app languages. However, if I delete Russian from preferred languages list then my app reverts to Polish (which is stored in the default values folder) whenever user chooses Russian as his in-app language.

My min SDK version is 20. I tested this using API 26 emulator.

I have written this test method:

```java
    public static void test(@NonNull Context appContext) {
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            return;
        }

        Resources appRes = appContext.getResources();
        Configuration appConfig = appRes.getConfiguration();

        Log.d("LanguageUtilsTest", "DEFAULT -> " + appContext.getString(R.string.cancel));

        Configuration configEN = new Configuration(appConfig);
        configEN.setLocale(new Locale("en", "GB"));
        Context contextEN = appContext.createConfigurationContext(configEN);
        Log.d("LanguageUtilsTest", "EN -> " + contextEN.getString(R.string.cancel));

        Configuration configRU = new Configuration(appConfig);
        configRU.setLocale(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
        Context contextRU = appContext.createConfigurationContext(configRU);
        Log.d("LanguageUtilsTest", "RU -> " + contextRU.getString(R.string.cancel));
    }
```

If my system language list looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/coOSf.jpg
The results are:

```
DEFAULT -> Anuluj
EN -> Cancel
RU -> Отменить
```

If I remove all languages except Polish (Polski).
The results are:

```
DEFAULT -> Anuluj
EN -> Anuluj
RU -> Anuluj
```

I've tried adding `resConfigs "en", "ru"` in my gradle but it didn't help.

Any advice?